# android - content not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, android-studio, protocol-buffers

After 2 hours of unsuccessfully searching for solution I've decided to ask a question here.

I've downloaded a project from a git repository which used to work in August. Android Studio made me update classpath and buildToolsVersion in build.gradle files. After doing this I'm getting an error of app:mergeDebugResources failed.

```css
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:compileLint
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:preBuild
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:preReleaseBuild
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:checkReleaseManifest
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:preDebugBuild
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:preDebugTestBuild
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6171Library
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:prepareReleaseDependencies
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:compileReleaseAidl
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:mergeReleaseResources
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:processReleaseResources
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:generateReleaseSources
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:compileReleaseJava
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:extractReleaseAnnotations
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ScavengerHunt-endpoints:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6171Library
:app:prepareScavenegetHuntScavengerHuntEndpointsUnspecifiedLibrary
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

D:\scaveneget-hunt\app\src\main\res\protobuf\protocol.proto:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> D:\scaveneget-hunt\app\src\main\res\protobuf\protocol.proto:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I've tried to delete .idea also opened this file in hexeditor but there's nothing at 0:0. Let me know if I should include more info.

--UPDATE--

If I delete everything from .proto file it fails because of "premature end of file" which seems OK. If I write the code below the error message is "content is not allowed" again.

```css
message Im{
    required string text = 1;
}
```

Am I missing something in Android Studio's settings?